# Analyticity and Complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic in a domain D and $f\neq0$. Let $\gamma$ be a curve homotopic to a point in D. I want to show that $$\int_{\gamma}\frac {f'(z)} {f(z)}=0$$

Honestly I don't know how to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: $$\dfrac{f'(z))}{f(z)} = (\log(f(z)))'$$ and the only place where $\log(f(z))$ can have issues is when $f(z) = 0$.

Comment: but what does this have to do with $\gamma$ being homotopic to a point in D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classic theorem in Complex Analysis is the following (called the Argument Principle):

Let $f$ be meromorphic in a domain $D$ and suppose that $a_1,...,a_n$ are zeroes of $f$ and $b_1,...,b_m$ are poles of $f$, all counted according to multiplicity (e.g. if $f$ has a double pole at $c$, then we count $c$ twice, that is $c=b_i, c=b_j$, for some $1≤i<j≤m$). Let $\gamma$ be a path homotopic in $D$ to a point such that $a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_m \not \in \gamma$, then

$\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int _\gamma\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\sum\limits_{k=i}^{n}Ind_{\gamma}(a_i)+\sum\limits_{k=i}^{m}Ind_{\gamma}(b_i)$,

where $Ind_{\gamma}(c)$ is the winding number (or index) of $c$.

Now the proof of this relies on the Residue Theorem, so that is why we need the path to be homotopic to a point.

Now, since your function has no poles and zeroes, the integral is zero.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering my confusion. i understand the problem clearly now.

Answer (score 1):

By Argument principle, your integral counts the number of zeros inside the curve, in this case zero. The condition makes sure that the $D$ has no holes inside the curve, so the principle applies.

Comment: yeah i forgot that f is nonzero. thanks for pointing that out!